# Error when using variable with jQuery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the id of a `td` to perform some functions on them. I have multiple of these classes but I need this particular `td`.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<table border=1 class="yo">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td class="sigh">b</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table border=1 class="yoyo">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td class="dSigh" id="df">y</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
 var abc = $('.yo').next().attr('class');
 console.log(abc);
 var tableBodyCols2 = $('.' + abc + '> .dSigh').attr('id');
 console.log(tableBodyCols2);
```

Result I am getting:

yoyo

*undefined*

Expected Result:

yoyo

df

Comment: I think you need a space before the `>`, i.e. `$('.' + abc + ' > .dSigh').attr('id');`. But also, `.dSigh` is not a [*direct child*](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) of `.yoyo`. So you might try `$('.' + abc + ' .dSigh').attr('id');`.

Comment: @showdev, you are a lifesaver!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (`>`) because `.dSigh` is not a direct child of `.yoyo`. You need to use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) (space):

```js
var abc = $('.yo').next().attr('class');
console.log(abc);
var tableBodyCols2 = $('.' + abc + ' .dSigh').attr('id');
console.log(tableBodyCols2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 class="yo">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td class="sigh">b</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border=1 class="yoyo">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>x</td>
      <td class="dSigh" id="df">y</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```